# Android byte64 significantly reduces image quality

Tags: android, image, base64, decode, encode

I have already tried various solutions posted here and none of them was working.

I basically take a picture with a camera, convert it into the byte array, put it into DB and when I want to display the image I get the byte array, decode the image and set it to the image view. But then my image quality is much much worse than before.

Here is my encoding code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_TAKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        photoImageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
        encodedPhoto = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, 0);

    }
```

And here is my decoding code (photoBase64Str1 is the string of bytes I get from the database):

```
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photoBase64Str1, Base64.DEFAULT);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        final Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length, options);

        photo1.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

I have tried playing with Bitmap Factory options but none of them gave me the results I wanted.

Comment: its not base64 that is making the image quality tank, it is `selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);`

Comment: Experimented with that too. Nothing useful

Comment: `Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`. That is not the original image but only a thumbnail of it. So if you compare that with the original...

Comment: Side note, why aren't you saving the image to a file and a pointer to the image in the database? It can be a performance issue to store large binary blobs in an android database

Comment: It is easier for me to store image like that. Base64 String is a part of a object  i store in a firebase database